# visual studio code - mongoose (custom) schema methods are not recognized after importing the model into another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, visual-studio-code

Expected functionality: autocomplete of object methods and recognition of method parameters

Actual functionality: no autocomplete or method parameters recognized. hovering over the method displays `any` on the tooltip (rather than the parent object to that method)

Any help? I just switched from Webstorm to VSC today and ran into this issue.

**Structure and code**

**custom static methods (exporting the userProfile model)**:
`/database/profileModel.js`

```
userSchema.statics.addProfile = function(formData){
        this.create(formData, e => e ? console.log(e) : false);
    };

    userSchema.statics.getProfile = function(userName){
        return this.findOne({userName : userName});
    };

    userSchema.statics.getProfileItem = function(userName, item){
        return this.findOne({userName : userName}, item);
    };
```

**API endpoint (exporting the router)**: `/routes/APIendpoint.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = module.exports = express.Router();


const userProfile = require('../database/profileModel').userProfile;
userProfile.getProfileItem()
```

@Neil Lunn Here is the proof of it working in Webstorm - since you are so certain it shouldn't. The following is **WITHOUT ADVANCED SCHEMAS**:

[image]

Also this did not fix the issue. Here is the new code using advanced schemas. It recognizes the methods within that file **but not** in the other file where it is imported.

```
class User {

// general static methods
    addProfile(formData) {
        this.create(formData, error => console.log(error));
    }

    getProfile(userName) {
        return this.findOne({userName : userName});
    }

    getProfileItem(userName, item) {
        return this.findOne({userName : userName}, item);
    }
}

userSchema.loadClass(User);

const userProfile = module.exports = mongoose.model('userProfile', userSchema);
```

Comment: for the record the method DOES work in practice. i am purely talking about the autocomplete / parameter recognition

Comment: That's just not going to work since a Mongoose Schema is not actually an ES6 Class. If you expect something like that to work, you actually need to base your design off of ES6 class. See [Advanced Schemas](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/advanced_schemas.html) in the mongoose documentation. As you note yourself this is not a "mongoose functionality" problem, but if you want things like "autocomplete" to work in your editor, then you need to give it something it can possibly understand.

Comment: thank you. is this something that vsc can't handle (unless it is an ES6 class)? in webstorm it worked as expected and was very useful when dealing with big projects

Comment: `.statics.` is just a property on a complex object "instance" and not actually something that can be inspected by an IDE.

Comment: I see. I wonder how intelliJ / webstorm were able to inspect it then?

Comment: English is not a problem. I am a beginner asking questions. You are not obligated to answer - especially with such a rude tone. I am telling you - know it all - that it WORKS in webstorm. Webstorm detects this exact code and allows autocomplete and parameter recognition. 

I will work on learning about advanced schemas - it seems like the correct way to go. But that doesn't settle my curiosity as to why it fails in VSC but works in Webstorm.

Comment: I posted proof of it working without advanced schemas. I guess we both learned something today.

Comment: @vampiire did you ever figure out a solution for this (without advanced schemas) 

Comment: @nachocab unfortunately I did not and I think neil was too upset about being wrong to explore a solution with me.

Comment: lol I see he deleted his incredibly rude responses. oh well - I must have gone crazy and started arguing with myself according to the current history of comments...

Comment: wow 5 years later and I am still referencing this empty question... You would think in 5 years there would have been a way developed to deal with statics in mongoose via IDE documentation tools